# How to sort float value with hyphen in descending order in grid using extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I have a grid in my application. It contains the field value stock. I want to sort the field in descending order. The stock field contains a value with a positive float number and negative float value and hyphen value. I want to always display all hyphen values in last rows. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

e.g

```
**stock**              I want to sort in descending order 

45.44                      56.56
56.56                      56.23  
-                          45.44
43.25                      43.25
-23                         -23
-                            -
56.23                        -
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the natural order. In natural order hyphens ( representing the value zero ) should come between positive and negative values.

To achieve such custom orders, ExtJs allows you to define a [sorting function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter-cfg-sorterFn). In your store, you would define someting like :

```
sorters: [{
    sorterFn: function(value1, value2){
        if (value1 === value2) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (value1 == '-') return -1;
        if (value2 == '-') return 1;
        return parseFloat(value1) < parseFloat(value2) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}]
```